# ASP.NET MVC5 code event in Controller should reload View

Tags: asp.net, view, controller, signalr, eventhandler

In my MVC5 application, users log in from external software without a separate login. After some times the external application can be closed and in this case a login form should appear.
I receive an event

```
Software.DataChange + = delegate ()
{
.... code goes here
IsUserLoggedIn = false;
};
```

And now the globally defined variable IsUserLoggedIn changes. 
Now the login view should be called. And that's where my problems begin. 
Can I do this in the controller? 
Or can I assign a field via SignalR and then trigger a reload of the page? SignalR is already used for some progress bars.

Thanks

Ottilie

Comment: You should do it where you have access to the HttpContext. First clear session related values and then redirect the response to the login page. You don't need SignalR for that since it has to be in server side.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I am unable to call a new view from the event delegate. I can call System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear(), but then neither RedirectToAction nor Response.Redirect works. Return type of the anonymus function is always void.

Comment: Set a value for session. Make a global filter checks for the value when it is set ends the session and redirects the responses until user logs in again and unset the value.

Comment: The session does not end depending on the event, i. the event can occur and the session takes another minute or more to complete. As long as the page may not remain open. I have solved the problem with SignalR by sending a SignalR message in an extra function of the Hub and then the client responds and loads the login page. Thank you very much, Eldar, for your help.